# Group arguments under a 'Custom' category in the TFS 2012 build template

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am working on TFS 2012 deployment build. I want to group arguments under a 'Custom' category in the build template as shown in the image below,

[image]

That is,

```
3. Custom
    > Web
      1. Source:
      2. Target:
    > Console
      1. Source:
      2. Target:
```

How to do it? Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Create a custom build process template** as it is described in [Customize your build process template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx). You've probably already done that.
2. **Create a custom build activity DLL** as it is described in [Use and develop custom build process activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850441.aspx). Again, you've probably done that. We will add our custom build parameter classes to this assembly.
3. **Add the parameter class.** This class will hold your parameter values:

   ```
   [BuildExtension(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
   [Serializable]
   [TypeConverter(typeof(SourceTargetSettingsConverter))]
   public class SourceTargetSettings 
   {
       [DisplayName("1. Source")]
       [Description("Description for Source")]
       [Browsable(true)]
       public string Source { get; set; }

       [DisplayName("2. Target")]
       [Description("Description for Target")]
       [Browsable(true)]
       public string Target { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. **Add the type converter.** The parameter editor will only display its contents if your class is attributed with an `ExpandableObjectConverter` or a class derived from that type:

   ```
   public class SourceTargetSettingsConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
       {
           return destinationType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
       }

       public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
       {
           var parameters = (SourceTargetSettings) value;
           if (destinationType == typeof (string))
           {
               return "This appears in the right column of the parameters editor.";
           }

           return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
       }
   }
   ```
5. **Add the parameters to your process.** Build your custom assembly, add a reference to it in process template project, open your process template and add new arguments. Type them with your custom parameters class and create default values:

   [image: Process Parameters]
6. **Add parameter metadata.** As MrHinsh has stated in his answer, we still have to add a custom group. Look for `Metadata` in the arguments list and open the editor. Add two metadata items and refer to your process parameters:

   [image: Add Metadata]
7. **Upload.** Save your process template. Checkin both your custom assembly and your customized process template. Open the build process editor for a build process that uses your custom template, or reopen it.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and detail steps. I was able to achieve until step 7. In our organization, we have load balanced server in production, I wanted to group the custom parameter as shown below, Web > Server 1 1. Source 2. Target and then another subgroup > Server 2 > 1. Source 2. Target.

Comment: If you need a deeper hierarchy, you can nest the parameter classes using properties. Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you open and edit your .xaml build template you should see a parameter pre-configured called "meta*". If you select it and click the ellipse that is presented you will get the options that you are looking for.